# Specified cast is not valid - DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm building an application and I'm using a .dll that requires a param "Level" to be set to either gold, silver or bronze. Level is a public enum Level in the .dll.

To select either gold, silver or bronze I'd like to have it read from a dataGridView to save me from editing the source every time I want to change it however I keep getting the unhandles exception Specified cast is not valid.

This is my code.

```
var testLevel = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value == null ? Level.All : (Level)(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2]).Value; // exception occurs on this line
var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
{
    Level = testLevel,
};
```

So, how could I go about making level read from the DVG correctly without problems?

Thanks.

Edit: I've tested it with comboBoxes and it works great, but I'd really like it to work via DGV.

Comment: What is the value of `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value == null`?

Comment: Nobody knows what you are hiding in those cells :) Check in debugger what's there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Enum.Parse to parse string into enum you need.

```
Level levelValue = (Level) Enum.Parse(typeof(Level), (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2]).Value);
```

Also use a check String.IsNullOrEmpty instead of dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value == null

As an example you can use:

```
Level levelValue;        
var value = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2]).Value;
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Level), value))  
   levelValue = (Level) Enum.Parse(typeof(Level), value)
else
   levelValue = Level.All
```